# How to get list of parents and person in a recursive list with linq without children?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a self relating object via a list. How can I get a list of objects that are either a parent or or a person(has no children) and not any items which are child of parent please?

Also, there could be a case of Parent/Child/Grand-Child so only the parent would be selected.

Here is my test object

```
public class MyObj
{
    public MyObj()
    {
        MyList = new List<MyObj>();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<MyObj> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code with some attempts, both of which result in zero items. I need to compare using the Id too.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var parent = new MyObj() {Id = "parent"};
    var child = new MyObj() { Id = "child" };
    parent.MyList.Add(child);

    var person = new MyObj() { Id = "person" };

    var list = new List<MyObj>();
    list.Add(parent);
    list.Add(child);
    list.Add(person);

    //-- Expected result
    // parent
    // person

    //attempt 1
    List<MyObj> all2 = list.Select(sm => sm).ToList();
    List<MyObj> x = list.SelectMany(sm => sm.MyList.Except(all2)).ToList();

    //attempt2
    List<MyObj> parentsAndOphans = list.Where(w => list.All(w2 => list.Find(f => f.Id != w2.Id) == null)).ToList();


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `ID` is unique:

```
var children = new HashSet<string>(list.SelectMany(x => x.MyList.Select(c => c.Id)));
var results = list.Where(x => !children.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

`HashSet` makes it *O(n)* problem. If you don not want to use `HashSet` to you can perform much slower (probably *O(n^2)*) query:

```
var results = list.Where(x => !list.Any(c => c.MyList.Contains(x))).ToList();
```

You could also add `Parent` property to your class:

```
public MyObj Parent { get; set; }
```

and perform simple `Parent == null` check:

```
var results = list.Where(x => x.Parent == null).ToList();
```